# Autofill method of Range class failed - 1004 Excel 2016

Tags: excel, autofill

I've looked at all the threads on this topic and can't find the answer to my getting the error.
It was working perfectly then suddenly getting this error.
Here's my code:

```
If RH = True Then SourceRange = "A9:A10" Else SourceRange = "A9:A9"
    DestinationRange = "A10:A" & jl
    If DestinationRange <> SourceRange Then
         Range(SourceRange).AutoFill Destination:=Range(DestinationRange), Type:=xlFillSeries
     End If
```

RH is true in this example.
jl=30
A9:A10 = 1

I have tried selecting the sourcerange first, no change. I've tried using sheets("") with the sheetname for each range (same sheet), no change.

Comment: `DestinationRange = "A9:A" & jl`. The destination range must include the source range.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. I knew I just had to ask for help and I would figure it out. I'm not sure why it suddenly changed, but I have to include the ENTIRE source range in the destination range.